# Login attempts on production server resulting in SessionUnavailableException

Tags: php, symfony, session, authentication, fosuserbundle

I am experiencing failing sessions all of a sudden on a website when users attempt to log in, resulting in a *[SessionUnavailableException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FtSB.png)*. The documentation describes this as something which occurs when the client cannot accept the session info such as cookies being disabled, or expired sessions.  However we are experiencing this in multiple browsers across all our branches on this particular site on platform.sh while our local development environments work flawlessly. We have verified cookies enabled on all browsers used for testing.

**Host:** Platform.sh

**Framework:** Symfony 3.2 / FOS User Bundle 2.0.1

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Visit the login URL
2. Attempt to login with a user granted the ROLE_ADMIN privelege

**Outcome:**

You are immediately redirected back to the login page, unauthenticated (anonymous user).

**Expected outcome:**

- You will be logged in as the correct user and redirected to the
  administration area.

This has just recently started occurring on platform with this site, and no code changes have been applied since previous successful login attempts.

**Other Attempts**

We were initally using file based session storage.  Platform support recommended the use of Redis or Database session storage.

We attempted Redis session storage first using the SNC Redis bundle with PHPRedis, and were able to successfully store sessions in our development environments in Redis as well as on their staging branch on the production server, however the same exception is thrown and the user is still redirected to the login page anonymously.

Our second attempt was to use database storage utilizing Symfony's PDO session handler, and we experienced the exact same thing.  Session information is successfully stored in their database however, we are still being redirected to the login page anonymously and the SessionUnavailableException is thrown.

This is the image from the profiler showing the session exception we encounter at platform.sh.

[image]

Following are the relevant pieces from the config.yml and security.yml on the latest attempt utilizing the PDO session storage:

```
#config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: parameters_platform.php }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
parameters:
    locale: en
framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret: "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.pdo
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.redis
        default_redis_provider: %redis_host%

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes:
        - '::fields.html.twig'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        server_version: '10.0'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: trueredis
        metadata_cache_driver:
        query_cache_driver: redis
        result_cache_driver: redis

# FOS Users
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: FlyEvv\UserBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: Admin

# Redis
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: phpredis
            alias: default
            dsn: %redis_host%
        session:
            type: phpredis
            alias: session
            dsn: %redis_host%
        doctrine:
            type: phpredis
            alias: doctrine
            dsn: %redis_host%
    session:
        client: session
        prefix: foo
    doctrine:
        metadata_cache:
            client: doctrine
            entity_manager: default          # the name of your entity_manager connection
            document_manager: default        # the name of your document_manager connection
        result_cache:
            client: doctrine
            entity_manager: [default, read]  # you may specify multiple entity_managers
        query_cache:
            client: doctrine
            entity_manager: default
        second_level_cache:
            client: doctrine
            entity_manager: default
```

---

```
#security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

---

Ultimately I feel like this is an issue with the host considering the same code checkout works fine in other environments. However platform's support is rather slow, so I thought I'd throw it out here and see if the experts have any thoughts.

Thanks for looking and if there's further information I can provide please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will help, but as you are not experiencing this in dev, but out in production.

I've seen this when your header size is too large. so basically in production you have much larger header sizes due to analytics being enabled. This in turn takes you over the header size limit for the app server.

Comment: Thats an interesting thought, and thank you.  I dug through the error logs on the app server and didn't find anything in those regards, and nothing in the profiler indicates such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead and answer this, as I've discovered the issue and hopefully it might help someone else out.

Apparently another developer on our team changed a cache setting on the default route in `.platform/routes.yaml`. Most likely through the platform.sh control panel. There is a "Cookies to Whitelist" setting which was (for reasons yet unknown to me) set to "No Cookies".  Setting this back to all cookies fixed the issue.

For Reference:
https://docs.platform.sh/configuration/routes/cache.html#basic-usage